# Finding Skylight Replacement Dome

Tags: roof, skylight

My home was built in 1986, and the skylight acrylic dome looks ready to break any moment now.  I want to replace the dome but I can't for the life of me find anywhere that sells them with the setup that I have.

I think its called dome over curb or curb mounted? But the dome slides over the curb with no external frame, screws are ran through the side.  The curb measures 25.5" across.

Given I haven't been able to find a replacement, should I look into different styles (tempered glass or installing a frame)?

[image: Current Skylight]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purchase a new curb mounted unit of the same size as this old one *(in some unique cases it may require a special order if your unit is an odd-ball size)*. Then
just remove the whole existing skylight from the existing curbing. Peel off the old foam sealer material that is on top of the curbing and then lay down new sealer strip. Finally set on the new skylight and screw through its side holes into the curbing to secure into place.

Comment: Where do you recommend finding one?  The usual stores don't seem to carry any like this

Comment: @Jeff - Making product recommendations is something we try to avoid here.